# C++ Reference to templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class with several different instances which I would like to reference with a common type:

```
template <int par>
class Worker
{
public:
   int foo() { return m_par; }
   
private:
   static constexpr int m_par = par;
};

class B
{
private:
   Worker<10> m_worker1;
   Worker<20> m_worker2;
   Worker<30> m_worker3;
};
```

I can obviously define a reference to `m_worker1`:

```
const Worker<10>& ref = m_worker1;
```

But I am looking in a way to change the type of this reference (or maybe a pointer) in a way that it can refer to any of the instances of the templated class `Worker`, i.e being able to set it pointing to `m_worker1`, `m_worker2` or `m_worker3`.

What type would work here? `auto`, `void*` or another deduction? I am using C11.

Comment: None. Those classes don't have a common base class, so you can't access them that way.

Comment: A `Foo<T>` and a `Foo<U>` are two completly different types as far as C++ is concerned.  You'll need to give them a common base class or use a `variant`/`any` object to hold them.

Comment: This way you cannot use one pointer type to point all of diferent templates. One solution is to make interface with method foo(), implemented that interface with Worker and now you can have Interface pointer

Answer (score 1):

`Worker` is a class template. It is a template. It is not a class. To create an instance you first instantiate the template: `Worker<10>` is a class. `Worker<20>` is a different distinct class. As those are two types that have nothing in common there is no type that would allow you to store a reference to object of either type.

You can add a common base class:

```
struct Worker_base {};


template <int par>
class Worker : public Worker_base 
{
public:
   int foo() { return m_par; }
   
private:
   static constexpr int m_par = par;
};


int main() {
   Worker<10> m_worker1;
   Worker<20> m_worker2;
   Worker<30> m_worker3;

   Worker_base& m1 = m_worker1;
}
```

You could implement methods common to all workers in the base.

---

> What type would work here? auto, [...]

`auto` is not a type. It is merely a placeholder you can use when the compiler can deduce the type. When there is no common type then `auto` does not help either.

> [...] `void*` [...]

Do not use `void*`. C++ has better alternatives for type erasure. There is `std::any` to hold any type and `std::variant` for a limited set of possible types.

> I am using C11.

I suppose you mean C++11. C11 is the C standard from 2011. `std::any` and `std::variant` are both C++17. Consider to upgrade to a more recent standard if you want to use them rather than polymorphism via inheritance.

Comment: having the `m1` defined this way, could you please propose me a code snippet to call foo() methods of any of `m_worker1` / `m_worker2` / `m_worker3` instances, via the base class reference?

Comment: @SebastianGreen Add `foo` to the base class as a *pure virtual function*.